# Creating Numeric Battle System Backend in Java

Tags: java, oop

I've been trying to debug this simple battle system I've been attempting to achieve. I'm at a severely basic level and have made a debugging main file to figure out the source of the problem.
The main battle functions I've created:

```
package great;
import great.Player;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class battleFunc {

    public static void start(Player pLayer, Player Enemy){
        while(pLayer.getHealth() > 0 || Enemy.getHealth() > 0){
            String result = askPlayer();

            if(result.equals("Defend")){
                playerDefend(pLayer, Enemy);
            }

            if(result.equals("Hit")){
                playerHit(pLayer, Enemy);
            }

            EnemyHit(pLayer, Enemy);
        }
    }

    public static String askPlayer(){
        String x;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What will you do?");
        x = scanner.nextLine();

        return x;
    }

    public static void reportEnemyHealth(Player Enemy){
        System.out.println(Enemy.getName() + "'s health is: " + Enemy.getHealth());
    }

    public static void reportPlayerHealth(Player pLayer){
        System.out.println(pLayer.getName() + "'s health is: " + pLayer.getHealth());
    }

    public static int reportPlayerHit(Player pLayer, Player Enemy){
        int x = pLayer.getStrength() - Enemy.getDefense();
        return x;
    }

    public static void reportEnemyHit(Player pLayer, Player Enemy){
        System.out.println(Enemy.getName() + " hit for " + (Enemy.getStrength() - pLayer.getDefense()));
    }

    public static void playerDefend(Player pLayer, Player Enemy){
        int x = Enemy.getStrength() - (pLayer.getDefense() + 1);

        if (x <= 0) {x = 0;}

        pLayer.setHealth(pLayer.getHealth() - x);
        reportEnemyHit(pLayer, Enemy);
    }

    public static void playerHit(Player pLayer, Player Enemy){
        int x = pLayer.getStrength() - Enemy.getDefense();

        if (x <= 0){x = 0;}

        Enemy.setHealth(4);
        reportPlayerHit(pLayer, Enemy);
    }

    public static void EnemyHit(Player pLayer, Player Enemy){
        int x = Enemy.getStrength() - pLayer.getDefense();

        if (x <= 0){x = 0;}

        pLayer.setHealth(pLayer.getHealth() - x);
        reportEnemyHit(pLayer, Enemy);
    }
}
```

The Player class used for players and enemies:

```
package great;

public class Player {
    private int health;
    private String name;
    private int lvl;
    private int defense;
    private int strength;

    public Player(String x){
        name = x;
        lvl = 1;
    }

    public int getHealth(){
        return health;
    }   

    public void setHealth(int x){
        health = x;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }   

    public void setName(String x){
        x = name;
    }

    public int getLVL(){
        return lvl;
    }   

    public void setLVL(int x){
        x = lvl;
    }

    public int getDefense(){
        return defense;
    }

    public void setDefense(int x){
        x = defense;
    }

    public int getStrength(){
        return strength;
    }

    public void setStrength(int x){
        x = strength;
    }
}
```

The main file I've used to test the code:

```
package great;
import great.Player;
import great.battleFunc;

public class MainG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player guy = new Player("Deez Nuts");
        guy.setHealth(20);
        guy.setStrength(7);
        guy.setDefense(2);
        Player fuckboi = new Player("Fuckboi");
        fuckboi.setHealth(10);
        fuckboi.setStrength(3);
        fuckboi.setDefense(1);

        battleFunc.start(guy, fuckboi);
    }
}
```

When the main file is run all attack values return and print as 0 and no health is removed. Why is this?

Comment: In battlefunc `while(pLayer.getHealth() > 0 || Enemy.getHealth() > 0)` should be AND, not OR. With OR the battle continues until both the player and the enemy's health is at 0.

Comment: What is happening is when playerHit() is called it for some reason is returning a 0 in the math. That has applied to all the other Hit and Defend methods I've created. So when the HP is printed back no HP has been drained as the values all return 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
public void setDefense(int x){
    x = defense;
}
```

Doesn't set the player's defense to x, but sets x to the defense of the player. Just swap `x` with `defense` and the values should be updated properly. Same applies to `setStrength(...)`. The reason why the math returns 0 is simply that the strength and defense of both players is 0.

Comment: Thank you so much. I probably should have looked a little harder. Feel a bit inexperienced but thanks anyways. Cheers!

Comment: @DattManiels NP :) that's just a matter of time and training